# Clip top side of UIImage in ellipse shape

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I've got the following screen design :

[image]

I want to render `MKMapView` in `UIImage`, than apply elipsis `UIBezierPath` and clip top part of `UIImage`. How can i achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple implementation that you can follow to have the similar effect using CAShapeLayer.

- Create sufficiently ellipse path to fit height of your image view, but width can be adjusted to control curve.

[image]

- Create rectangular path to fit the size of the imageView, width and height should be match the size of imageView.

[image]

- Transform the circle in such a way that rectangular path is exactly at the middle of the circle.

[image]

Now, if you look at the image above, the rectangle has the same size as your imageView. If you somehow manage to remove the portion of shapes which are not intersected, you will have your desired effect.

And this will be the portion of the image that you will be masking,

[image]

This can be achieved quite easily using CAShapeLayer.

Here is a simple implementation that you can use,

```
let image = UIImage(named: "image.jpg")
let imageSize = image!.size

let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: imageSize))
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
imageView.image = image


let curveRadius: CGFloat = imageSize.width * 0.005
let invertedRadius: CGFloat = 1.0 / curveRadius

// draw ellipse in rect with big width, but same height
let ellipticalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width + 2 * invertedRadius * imageSize.width, imageSize.height))

// transform it to center of imageView
ellipticalPath.applyTransform(CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-imageSize.width * invertedRadius, 0))

// create rectangle path exactly similar to imageView
let rectanglePath = UIBezierPath(rect: imageView.bounds)

// translate it by 0.5 ratio in order to create intersection between circle and rectangle
rectanglePath.applyTransform(CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -imageSize.height * CGFloat(0.5)))

// append rectangle to elliptical path
ellipticalPath.appendPath(rectanglePath)


// create mask
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.frame = imageView.bounds
maskLayer.path = ellipticalPath.CGPath
imageView.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

And here is how it looks,

[image]

You can adjust the value of **curveRadius** to suit your need.

> Note: That the shape layer intersection is possible due to something called fillRule property on CAShapeLayer, which has a default value of kCAFillRuleNonZero. Read more about it here, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAShapeLayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CAShapeLayer/fillRule

Comment: Very nice answer! Huge thumbs up for the comments! 